# Why VS 2010 freezen when copying text editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, freeze

There was such a problem. Established a new framework and then Visual Studio 2010 began to freeze when copying text. How to fix it? Remove the new framework? How Microsoft manages to make all these misunderstandings? Disgusting!

Sorry for my bad english .... it'fault google translate.

Comment: There is an assumption that the problems are due to the conflict versions of VS 2010 and VS 2012 because of their incompatibility. I know how to fix this problem - remove the framework, but it is not the best solution. For example a new driver from AMD demanded the installation of a new version of the framework to function properly.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do this:-

Go to tools --> options --> text editor --> C#

and then disable **Auto list members and Parameter information.**

[image]

**EDIT:-**

This seems to be an issue with the Visual Studio but you may find the relevant information here. **[VS 2010 freezes when pasting text into the editor](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/664749/)**

**P.S.:-** *And it is not that Microsoft does nothing with its product or leaves a misunderstanding. Its just that even the best may sometimes skip few things.*

Comment: It does not help. I'm writing in C++.

Comment: @OpenGLcoder:- What are you trying to copy? Could you please provide some details?

Comment: Standard program code in the editor. But when there is a copy Visual Studio slows down a bit. While copying is unpleasant delay.

Comment: @OpenGLcoder:- I have updated my answer with the link which has reference to the same issue. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Not 'pasting' but 'copy'. Delay 1-2 second.

Comment: @OpenGLcoder:- And what is the count of lines that you want to copy?